# java code snippet to read file before and after packaging into jar

Tags: java, file, jar

i know this must have been answered a million times, but i can't seem to find it anywhere. So here goes: in my junit test I have this to access the file `foo.txt`**:**

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/foo.txt")
```

this works fine until I package it into a jar file. how should i edit my code so that it works in both cases?

thanks a lot

Comment: Where is foo.txt when you have packaged your code into a jar?

Comment: @seminolas put it in the root of Jar

Comment: once again, it _is_ in the root of the jar

Comment: then there is something else wrong

Comment: That's how I fetch files from JAR in my Java WebStart applications... Only difference is that I use ClassImInName.class.getResourceAsStream() instead of this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(). Works good.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your foo.txt is packaged in root of your jar file. I think that this file is probably present into file system, so when you are running the code from IDE it works, but for some reason it is not in jar.

Possible reason is if you are creating jar using ant script and configured the include pattern as *.class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the text file is packaged in the jar:

```
test.jar =>
    -> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    -> com/somepackage/ClassThatLoadsFooTxt.class
    -> foo.txt
```

If the class file and `foo.txt` is contained in the src folder like this:

```
   -> src/com/somepackage/ClassThatLoadsFooTxt.class
   -> src/foo.txt
```

make sure the `Class-Path` entry in your MANIFEST.MF points to src:

```
Class-Path: src/
```

Comment: Class-Path entry is irrelevant (and incorrect - there is no "src" directory in JAR file)